# React-Router won't respect deep links

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have the following code for route registration at my primary (main.tsx) entry point:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { browserHistory, IndexRoute, Route, Router } from "react-router";

import { About } from "../about/about";
import { Home } from "../home/home";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about/:id" component={About}>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("main")
);
```

I also have the following code for entry, output, and devServer in my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  {
        main:    "./wwwroot/common/main.tsx", // Starting point of linking/compiling Typescript and dependencies, will need to add separate entry points in case of not deving SPA
        common:  [ "q", "react", "react-dom", "react-router" ] // All of the "chunks" to extract and place in common file for faster loading of common libraries between pages
    },
    output: {
        path: "./dist/", // Where we want to host files in local file directory structure
        publicPath: "/", // Where we want files to appear in hosting (eventual resolution to: https://localhost:4444/)
        filename: "[name].js", // What we want end compiled app JS file to be called
    },

    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist", // Copy and serve files from dist folder
        port: 4444, // Host on localhost port 4444
        https: true, // Enable self-signed https/ssl cert debugging
        colors: true, // Enable color-coding for debugging (VS Code does not currently emit colors, so none will be present there)
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: "index.html"
        }
    },
```

Whenever I attempt to access /about/uniqueGuidHere directly or via a refresh, all that I receive are 404s (for all image files as well as the outputted common.js file and main.js file).  No additional routing code exists in the other .tsx files besides home where I have the links (with guids concat'd at the end of them).  Am I missing something?  Is something else required to allow deep linking with react-router?

Comment: as an FYI "index.html" exists at directory "./wwwroot/"

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that have also ran into this issue, I found a solution (at least for my problem).  It turned out the index.html file had relative paths (as opposed to deep paths).

For example, by changing the "script src" of "main.js" from "./main.js" to "/main.js" it began working (as being served utilizing webpack-dev-server).

Source for further reading can be found here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls